# How to find out if a property is an auto-implemented property with reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, automatic-properties

So in my case i am doing discovery of the structure of a class using reflection. I need to be able to find out if a property is an auto-implemented property by the PropertyInfo object. I assume that the reflection API does not expose such functionality because auto-properties are C# dependent, but is there any workaround to get this information?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could check to see if the `get` or `set` method is marked with the `CompilerGenerated` attribute. You could then combine that with looking for a private field that is marked with the `CompilerGenerated` attribute containing the name of the property and the string `"BackingField"`.

Perhaps:

```
public static bool MightBeCouldBeMaybeAutoGeneratedInstanceProperty(
    this PropertyInfo info
) {
    bool mightBe = info.GetGetMethod()
                       .GetCustomAttributes(
                           typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute),
                           true
                       )
                       .Any();
    if (!mightBe) {
        return false;
    }


    bool maybe = info.DeclaringType
                     .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                     .Where(f => f.Name.Contains(info.Name))
                     .Where(f => f.Name.Contains("BackingField"))
                     .Where(
                         f => f.GetCustomAttributes(
                             typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute),
                             true
                         ).Any()
                     )
                     .Any();

        return maybe;
    }
```

It's not fool proof, quite brittle and probably not portable to, say, Mono.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason, the Reflector told me the same in the meantime:) Should have thought of it earlier.

Comment: @3o4eTo: Just be forewarned that this not fool proof, brittle and possibly not portable to Mono.

Comment: Also take care of the exception when there is no getter on the property.

Comment: True. Why do we need to check for the attribute?

Comment: In addition to the other restrictions, this will only work for auto-props generated by C#. VB.NET compiler uses the pattern of just putting prefixing `_` to the auto-prop name, but does include the `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` attribute. The F# compiler does not use apply that attribute and uses yet another naming convention.

Comment: @NickStrupat could you please give some hints if these compiler inconsistencies are still the same now in 2017? I can't find any detailed documentation about these.

Answer (score 15):

This should do:

```
public static bool IsAutoProperty(this PropertyInfo prop)
{
    return prop.DeclaringType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                             .Any(f => f.Name.Contains("<" + prop.Name + ">"));
}
```

The reason is that for auto-properties the `Name` property of the backing `FieldInfo` would look like:

```
<PropertName>k__BackingField
```

Since characters `<` and `>` wouldn't appear for normal fields, a field with that kind of naming points to a backing field of an auto-property. As Jason says, its brittle still.

Or to make it a tad faster,

```
public static bool IsAutoProperty(this PropertyInfo prop)
{
    if (!prop.CanWrite || !prop.CanRead)
        return false;

    return prop.DeclaringType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                             .Any(f => f.Name.Contains("<" + prop.Name + ">"));
}
```