# Accessing property through string name

Tags: c#, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set object property through Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370641/how-to-set-object-property-through-reflection)

If I have the following program:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyIntProp {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string MyStringProp {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class MyMainClass
{
    private const string PropertyName = "MyIntProp";
    private MyClass _myClass;

    public MyMainClass()
    {
        _myClass = new MyClass();
        // _myClass.PropertyName = 5;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is be able to assign a value of `5` to the `MyIntProp` property. Is it possible to do this using a string name? I though I saw something like this done before using LINQ, but I can't seem to remember the syntax or where I found it.

Comment: You probably don't want to do this.  In all likelihood there is a better approach to solving your problem.  Reflection is a sledgehammer; don't use it to swat a fly.

Comment: Here's something similar with LINQ (possibly what you were referring to), for reference: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: I agree with @Servy.  From your example at least, you should definitely just do `_myClass.MyIntProp = 5;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Reflection with [GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method:

```
 typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(PropertyName).SetValue(_myClass, 5);
```

Comment: The only issue with using reflection is, doesn't the property name change if using automatic getter and setters? I want to say it appends `BackingField` or something like that to the name?

Comment: @icemanind But you're not trying to access the backing field directly, you're just trying to access the property.  Take a look at the method; it's `GetProperty`.  It's specifically designed to *get* a *property*.

Comment: @icemanind: well, with the property name changes automatically, I guess to need to have mechanism to to get proper name, could you revise question for more understanding?

Comment: @CuongLe: No, its okay. Servy is right and your solution will work because I am trying to get the property and not the backing field :)

Comment: I was looking at [this Stackoverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675975/reflection-get-fieldinfo-from-propertyinfo) and I saw that the accepted answer was appending `k__BackingField` to the property name. I missed the part where he was asking for the name of the private backing field.