# Simplest way to get all MemberInfos that reflect the state of an object?

Tags: c#, reflection, automatic-properties, fieldinfo

I need to get all members that represent the *exact* state of an object using reflection. So these members include fields (`FieldInfo`) and auto-properties (`PropertyInfo`). I can get all the `FieldInfo`s using

```
type.GetFields(); //ok some flags needed here
```

And get auto implemented properties as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210309/how-to-find-out-if-a-property-is-an-auto-implemented-property-with-reflection?lq=1):

```
public static bool MightBeCouldBeMaybeAutoGeneratedInstanceProperty(this PropertyInfo info)
{
    bool mightBe = info.GetGetMethod().HasCompilerGeneratedAttribute();
    if (!mightBe)
        return false;

    bool maybe = info.DeclaringType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                   .Where(f => f.Name.Contains(info.Name))
                                   .Where(f => f.Name.Contains("BackingField"))
                                   .Where(f => f.HasCompilerGeneratedAttribute())
                                   .Any();

    return maybe;
}

public static bool HasCompilerGeneratedAttribute(this MemberInfo mi)
{
    return mi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Any();
}
```

As the answerer says this is indeed brittle. Is there are more standard way of achieving this? I'm thinking, may be something with `BindingFlags` or so?

```
type.GetMembers(BindingFlags....) ?
```

Comment: is this for specific objects types, or for any object type? if you want to get state for specific types, and you own their code, you can add your own special attribute [ObjectState] to mark those fields

Comment: @omerschleifer for any object type. I'm thinking of handling it generically, than go and modify all those classes.

Comment: Do you need to treat auto-property backing fields differently from regular fields?  In my experience, `GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);` will grab them.  Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @JeremyTodd No I need not treat them differently, I just need them. Let me try your example. If it works, I'll inform you, and you may kindly make that an answer :)

Comment: @nawfal not sure what you want with 'public facing' but it sounds like you're trying to write your own serialization process to output the file to a text (or similar) file that be imported/exported from other applications. In which case, do a search for `Serialization` the work is already done for binary, xml and json based formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "exact state of the object" you simply mean all the instance fields it contains (if not, can you clarify?), then you should be able to do it with a single statement -- there's no significant difference between fields you declare explicitly, and backing fields for auto-properties that the compiler adds for you.  If you define a class:

```
public class FieldInfoTest
{
  private string testField;

  public string TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

...you can access them all in one fell swoop with

```
FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(FieldInfoTest).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                     BindingFlags.Public | 
                                                     BindingFlags.NonPublic);

foreach (var f in fields)
{
  Console.WriteLine(f.Name);
}
```

This will yield:

```
testField
<TestProperty>k__BackingField
```

Comment: Jeremy, +1 for the idea, might work in my case. But I would love to get the property instead (as `PropertyInfo`)

Comment: @nawfal Any particular reason you have a special interest in the auto-properties, though?  I mean, apart from the fact that they're implemented by compiler sugar, they're pretty much the same as regular properties under the hood.

Comment: In my case I need a handle to autoproperties for the fact that they are standalone member (from outside world at least), but not normal properties (which will have backing field). For eg, if there is a `Person` class like this: `int age; int Age { get { return age; } } string Name { get; set; }`, what all determine the a particular state of the object? It has to be the fields (since they form the basis of properties; externally the expose something else), and auto-properties which doesn't have backing fields - hence, `age` and `Name` for me.

Comment: Auto-properties do have backing fields, though.

Comment: Jeremy, they do, that's why I used "outside world" first. I hope you understood why I need auto-properties specifically. Since, as you said, they are properties in every sense under the hood, it will be nice if I get them as properties itself.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand yet. :)  I'm not getting why you want `PropertyInfo` for `string Name { get; set; }` but not for `int age; int Age { get { return age; } set { age = value; } }`, since they're more or less exactly the same under the hood.

Comment: that was a very stripped down example I gave you. The key is this point which I said "externally the expose something else". For example, take this `Person` class: `int dob; int Age { get { return CalculateAge(dob); } } string Name { get; set; }`. Here internally the state of the object is represented by backing fields, not what they expose to outside world isn't it? Take a more complex scenario like this: `int value; int Value { get { return Math.Abs(value); } } string Name { get; set; }`.

Comment: In scenarios like this there is no way the actual state can be obtained from properties (but auto-properties help).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29790/discussion-between-jeremy-todd-and-nawfal)

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy's answer is the best I could get. Here's another alternative (which I originally mentioned in question itself):

```
public static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetStateMembers(this Type t)
{
    return t.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field && !((FieldInfo)m).Name.Contains('<')
                     || m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property && ((PropertyInfo)m).IsAutoProperty());
}

public static bool IsAutoProperty(this PropertyInfo prop)
{
    if (!prop.CanWrite || !prop.CanRead)
        return false;

    return prop.DeclaringType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                             .Any(f => f.Name.Contains("<" + prop.Name + ">"));
}
```

More explanation on how that works here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16506710/661933

Little bit hackish, but this gives fields and auto-properties (unlike Jeremy's answer which gives only field infos).